# What is the meaning of the 'cld' column in 'microbenchmark'?

Tags: r, statistics, microbenchmark

I always thought that the `cld` column in the output of `microbenchmark` was a statistical ranking of the speed. However this is not true:

```r
> microbenchmark(
+   intmap = fintmap(), # slower
+   List   = flist(),
+   times = 5
+ )
Unit: microseconds
   expr     min      lq      mean  median       uq      max neval cld
 intmap 793.984 910.539 1145.8608 911.840 1290.529 1822.412     5  a 
   List   1.092   1.318  201.3712   1.639    3.660  999.147     5   b
```

So what is it? The doc only says it is a statistical ranking, but of what?

Or maybe it is a multiple comparison test of the speeds but the inequality of the standard deviations can cause such an issue? There's clearly an outlier in the second benchmark.

---

## Edit

It seems that my question was not clear. I know the meaning of the letters `a` and `b`, this is the classical way to report a Tukey test. But the results are not coherent here: `intmap` is slower but is ranked first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `cld` is a Compact Letter Display brought over from the package `multcomp`.

From that package: "Equal letters indicate no significant differences."

What I can't currently determine in whether or not it's meant to be ranked or just classified i.e. is `a` meant to be generally faster than `b` or just different?

The code in `microbenchmark::summary` is:

```
      ops <- options(warn=-1)
      mdl <- lm(time ~ expr, object)
      comp <- multcomp::glht(mdl, multcomp::mcp(expr = "Tukey"))
      res$cld <- multcomp::cld(comp)$mcletters$monospacedLetters
```

So from that, it appears to be generating a linear model `lm()` from the raw times (not the means etc), then setting up multiple comparisons object `glht()` for all-pair comparisons, then reducing that to a cld using `cld()`.

EDIT: Testing ranking:

```
a <- rnorm(1000)
a

microbenchmark(
  alpha = mean(a),
  beta = a/length(a) |> sum(),
  gamma = sum(a) / length(a),
  times = 10000,
  unit = "nanoseconds"
)

Unit: nanoseconds
  expr  min   lq    mean median   uq      max neval cld
 alpha 4700 5500 6325.56   5700 6800    37700 10000  a 
  beta 1700 2700 5307.55   2900 3300 12419800 10000  a 
 gamma  900 1100 1240.32   1100 1300    24000 10000   b

microbenchmark(
  gamma = sum(a) / length(a),
  alpha = mean(a),
  beta = a/length(a) |> sum(),
  times = 10000,
  unit = "nanoseconds"

Unit: nanoseconds
  expr  min   lq    mean median   uq      max neval cld
 gamma  900 1100 1214.29   1100 1200    23700 10000  a 
 alpha 4900 5500 6039.82   5700 6200    71900 10000   b
  beta 1700 2500 5459.20   3000 3200 12272900 10000   b
)
```

This would appear to demonstrate that, as suspected, the order of the entries in the table is listed as provided to `microbenchmark()`, and the cld are assigned sequentially based on this order NOT by the overall speed ranking.

edit 2: playing with ordering

```
d <- microbenchmark(
  alpha = mean(a),
  beta = a/length(a) |> sum(),
  gamma = sum(a + a - a) / length(a),
  times = 10000,
  unit = "nanoseconds"
)

print(d, order = "cld")

Unit: nanoseconds
  expr  min   lq    mean median   uq     max neval cld
  beta 1700 1900 2386.04   2000 2300   53400 10000   b
 alpha 5000 5500 6219.35   5700 6400   72700 10000  a 
 gamma 1900 2200 4378.53   2400 2600 8532200 10000  ab
```

Looks to me like it sorts the cld alphabetically as though it were a set of columns, so it sorts by a (blanks at the top) then by b (ditto) etc...

Comment: Thanks but then my results shown in the OP are not coherent.

Comment: I think (needs testing) that microbenchmark lists them in either the order they were supplied, or in alphabetical order.  The cld starts with a at the first rank by this ordering and adds additional letters as needed.  In other words, the cld is not a ranking, just a grouping.

Comment: I don't think so. As you can see, `a` is on the left of `b`, this is a way to show it is the first. I'm familiar with the Tukey test and this is how we report the results: `a` the group ranked first, `b` the second, etc.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Edited with a test. It appears this implementation does not follow that guideline that a is better/faster than b.

Comment: Thanks. That is strange.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent ordering by cld only adds to the oddness.

Comment: No, this is the usual practice ("Tukey cld" on Google). This is helpful to read the results.

Comment: Moreover look at the doc of `cld` in the **multcomp** package. There is an argument `decreasing=TRUE/FALSE`. I think it's a bug. I use **microbenchmark** for a very long time and that's the first time I see that.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent sorry, I did not explain myself.  I understand you are correct regarding standard practice, what I mean is that trying to use the `order = "cld"` argument only takes microbenchmark further from the expected behaviour!

Answer (score 1):

Compact Letter Display - It is from multcomp package, see *multcomp::cld*

[GitHub microbenchmark print.R Line 15](https://github.com/joshuaulrich/microbenchmark/blob/2054713e0508f0cff4eb833b5499e3e23bc62c1e/R/print.R#L15)

```
#' @note If the \code{multcomp} package is available a statistical
#' ranking is calculated and displayed in compact letter display from
#' in the \code{cld} column.
```

Comment: I knew that :-) My question was about the quantity which is compared.